# Time format in php excel export csv

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm using maat website excel to export data in my laravel project, here's my problem, I try to export a column of date like "`2016/09/08`" ,in console `var_dump()`, it works well, but in excel,it automatically trans into "`Sep-08`",I tried `$sheet->setColumnFormat('@')`,but it won't work,how can I get "`2016/09/08`" in excel csv file ?

Comment: Try to add a ' before the date: `'2016/09/08`.

Comment: MS Excel will parse dates from a csv file as it chooses, generally based on the MS Excel locale settings.... check what format is stored in the csv file by looking at it in a text editor; and if you want to control the format that is used, then avoid csv and use a native-format spreadsheet file

Comment: @gus42 thx ,I add a space in front of date ` 2016/09/08` and solved!~